# SELECT with foreign key and JOIN table MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with Contracts and Dates, in table contracts I can have subordinate contracts and superior contracts. I want to select count of sub contracts for every sup contract (something like select how many employees each manager has) in my table Contracts I have id_contract and parent_id.
I made this query:

```
SELECT 
count(sub.id_contract) AS count_sub_contracts,
sup.id_contract AS parent_contract, 
sup.contractor_name AS parent_contract_name
FROM Contracts sub 
JOIN Contracts sup ON sub.parent_id=sup.id_contract
GROUP BY parent_contract;
```

and the result was correct

[image]

Every contract has a few date and I want to also Select the latest date, but when I do it, I get incorrect values:

```
SELECT 
count(sub.id_contract) AS count_sub_contracts,
sup.id_contract AS parent_contract, 
sup.contractor_name AS parent_contract_name, 
MAX(DATE_FORMAT(d.date, "%Y-%m-%d")) date 
FROM Contracts sub 
JOIN Contracts sup ON sub.parent_id=sup.id_contract
JOIN Dates d ON sup.id_contract=d.id_contract 
GROUP BY parent_contract;
```

[image]

when I also group by date I get:
[image]
and I don't know what is wrong

Comment: are you sure the first sql was correct?

Comment: Yes, because in SELECT * FROM Contracts I counted how many times 66, 73, 75 and 77 appears in the parent_id column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you have now duplicated rows for each date. To prevent duplication you could make a date as a subquery, like this:

```
SELECT 
count(sub.id_contract) AS count_sub_contracts,
sup.id_contract AS parent_contract, 
sup.contractor_name AS parent_contract_name, 
d.date 
FROM Contracts sub 
JOIN Contracts sup ON sub.parent_id=sup.id_contract
JOIN (
    SELECT MAX(DATE_FORMAT(d.date, "%Y-%m-%d")) date, d.id_contract FROM 
    Dates GROUP BY d.id_contract
) d ON sup.id_contract=d.id_contract 
GROUP BY parent_contract;
```